# Exporting Pandas dataframe to csv capitalizes True to TRUE

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean

For simplicity purposes I have a dataframe that has 1 row/column that contains the string "True".

```
df=pd.DataFrame(["True"])
df.to_csv("df.csv")
```

When I export it to a csv, "True" becomes "TRUE". I don't understand this. Is there a way to prevent this? I only want it as "True"

Tried "true", "True". still capitalizes it to TRUE

Comment: Are  you opening the CSV file in Excel? If so, don't. Excel is terrible with CSV files. If you can't avoid using Excel, then you need to *import* the file and specify that column as text. You can't just open the file, you have to *import* it.

Comment: You are right. I'm using Numbers off Mac, and even Google Sheets but noticed the same thing. Opening that CSV file from a text editor or importing back into Python, looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Actually just using df.to_excel("df.xlsx") allows be to see my desired output.